# VBA handling of hours when greater than 24

Tags: excel, vba, time

I am dealing with a report that is automagically generated.  It contains hours that exceed a day.

[image: Picture depicts the formula bar with 1/1/1900 12:04:36 PM. Below is a cell with 36:04:36 highlighted in yellow.]

I need to pull the number from the cell in yellow and not the way it is listed in the formula line.  In case I am thinking about this incorrectly, my goal is to take the number of hours listed and find the number of tickets worked in that time.

For instance,

```
destSht.Range("B2").Value = (srcSht.Range("E5").Value / srcSht.Range("G5").Value)
```

However, the value shown in the hours field is 1.50399, so the calculation is wildly off.

If there is not a graceful way to handle this, I could have it check for the date (numbers less than 24 do not include the 1/1/1900 portion).

Comment: `1.50399` is `36:04:36`  Excel stores date time as a double.  You just need to format the resulting cell correctly: `destSht.Range("B2").NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm:ss"`

Comment: To add to the above, datetimes are stored as a double, where 1 = 1 day. If your "hours" field shows 1.50399 days, that is precisely correct. If you want to convert days to hours, multiply by 24. 1.50399*24=36.09576 hours. You then have to decide what to do about minutes - do you want half an hour to be "0.5" or "0:30"? If your calculation is going to be tickets per hour, you probably want to leave it as a decimal value, not a minutes value.

Comment: Thank you, Gentlemen.  I appreciate your insight.  That got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Scott and Kevin for their insight.  Here's what I ended up with...

```
destSht.Range("B2").Value = (srcSht.Range("E5").Value / (srcSht.Range("G5").Value*24))
```

I just hope this helps someone else.